# Optimization (with scipy.optimize.minimize) with multiple variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

I want to implement the Nelder-Mead optimization on an equation. But it does not contain only one variable, it contains multiple variables (one of them which is the unknown, and the others known.)

For instance at this example:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html

If my rosen(x) was

```
def rosen(x,y):
...     """The Rosenbrock function"""
...     return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**y + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)
```

instead of this that is mentioned on the example, how could i optimise it?
If i call

```
res = minimize(rosen, x0, method='nelder-mead',
...                options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

it says that needs two arguments
if i call

```
res = minimize(rosen(y), x0, method='nelder-mead',
...                options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

with y already defined previously on the code, i get the same error. While if I call it

```
res = minimize(rosen(x,y), x0, method='nelder-mead',
...                options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

I get an error that x is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing arguments to the objects is done with parameter `args`. Optimizing  `rosen(x,2)`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def rosen(x, y):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**y + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])

res = minimize(rosen, x0, args=(2,), method='nelder-mead',
               options={'xtol': 1e-8, 'disp': True})
```

Note that the variable `x` is a 5 dimensional vector, as you can see in the definition of the starting point `x0`, hence `rosen(x,2)` has five variables. If your you want to minimize `rosen(x,y)`, define a objective function

```
def rosen2(zz):
    return rosen(zz[:5], zz[5])
```